# How to bring data from parent directive to child directive in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have 2 directives as "chart" and "datapoint". Here the chart directive is the parent of the datapoint directive. I am trying to bring some data from parent directive to the children, but it throws an error.

Here is my directives:

```
"user strict";

angular.module("chartDirective", [])
    .directive('chart', function () {
        return {
                replace:true,
                transclude : true,
                templateUrl : '/views/directiveViews/svg.html',
                controller : function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
                    this.name="Afzil"; //setting up name.
                }
            }
    })

    .directive('datapoint', function () {
        return {
            replace : true,
            require :'^chart',
            template : '<circle cx="20" cy="20" ng-attr-r="{{radius}}" ng-attr-stroke-width="{{strokeWidth}}" fill="#FFF" stroke="#5B90BF" />',
            link : function (scope, element, attr, controller) {
                scope.radius = 4;
                scope.strokeWidth = 3;
                console.log(controller); //trying to console.
            }
        }
    })
```

The error I am getting is:

`https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$attrProvider%20%3C-%20$attr`

But using this link, I am not able to find a solution. Any one know what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are trying to pass $attr into your controller.  There is no $attr.  In the link function $attr is the third argument that gives you access to the attributes of the directive.

From the angular directives guide:

> Savvy readers may be wondering what the difference is between link and
>   controller. The basic difference is that controller can expose an API,
>   and link functions can interact with controllers using require.
>
> Best Practice: use controller when you want to expose an API to other
>   directives. Otherwise use link.

Here is a demonstration on how to pass attribute values from the parent controller (using require) to the child directive.

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/W46Gw5oYhisPN9hXuaTI?p=preview)

```
app.directive('chart', function () {
        return {
                replace:true,
                scope: true,
                controller : function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                    this.name="Afzil"; //setting up name.
                    this.myAttrVal = $attrs.myAttr;
                }
            }
    })

    .directive('datapoint', function () {
        return {
            replace : true,
            scope: true,
            require :'^chart',
            template : '<div>{{valFromChart}}</div>',
            link : function (scope, element, attr, chart) {
                scope.radius = 4;
                scope.strokeWidth = 3;
                scope.valFromChart = chart.myAttrVal;
                console.log('from chart: ' + chart.myAttrVal); //trying to console.
            }
        }
    })
```

In the datapoint directive, we pass some arbitrary value as an alias for the controller we have `require`'ed.  We can then access anything attached to that controller.

Comment: yes, it works. and thanks for making to understanding. but in the parent `directive` i have declared a couple of `attrs` still why this issue is? here my directive : `<chart height="400" width="600">
 <datapoint label="2000" d="20"></datapoint>
</chart>` I say i have `height` and `width`.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @3gwebtrain   there is, however, `$attrs` (with the `s` at the end) that could be injected into the controller

Comment: `parent controller (using require) ` - is there any other way too..? can you explore...

Comment: Did you see the demo?  I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: yes. thanks. you say using require approch to get the attrs. i am askig withot or any other way can we consume parents attra from child?

Comment: @3gwebtrain, you don't need `require`. attributes are available both in the controller - via injectable `$attrs` - and in the `link` function as a third parameter.